# error Unable to resolve module - while generating debug APK

Tags: react-native, create-react-native-app

> error Unable to resolve module /usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro-config/node_modules/metro-runtime/src/modules/empty-module.js

Answer (score 0):

> Just by running this in the project directory, it worked for me!

```
npm i -g react-native-cli
```